# Не устанавливается pygame, в чём проблема?

Tags: python, pygame, pip

Устанавливаю через pip.
Версия python 3.11.
Ошибка:

```
Collecting pygame
  Using cached pygame-2.1.2.tar.gz (10.1 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'

  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [43 lines of output]
  
  
  WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
  Using WINDOWS configuration...
  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
    File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
    File "D:\Temp\pip-install-u057jgk1\pygame_5193ac699b2a45d98182069b38032fbb\setup.py", line 359, in <module>
      buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
    File "D:\Temp\pip-install-u057jgk1\pygame_5193ac699b2a45d98182069b38032fbb\buildconfig\config.py", line 225, in main
      deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "D:\Temp\pip-install-u057jgk1\pygame_5193ac699b2a45d98182069b38032fbb\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 497, in main
      and download_win_prebuilt.ask(**download_kwargs):
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "D:\Temp\pip-install-u057jgk1\pygame_5193ac699b2a45d98182069b38032fbb\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 290, in ask
      update(x86=x86, x64=x64)
    File "D:\Temp\pip-install-u057jgk1\pygame_5193ac699b2a45d98182069b38032fbb\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 273, in update
      download_prebuilts(download_dir, x86=x86, x64=x64)
    File "D:\Temp\pip-install-u057jgk1\pygame_5193ac699b2a45d98182069b38032fbb\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 124, in download_prebuilts
      download_sha1_unzip(url, checksum, temp_dir, 1)
    File "D:\Temp\pip-install-u057jgk1\pygame_5193ac699b2a45d98182069b38032fbb\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 58, in download_sha1_unzip
      raise ValueError(
  ValueError: url:https://www.pygame.org/ftp/jpegsr9d.zip should have checksum:ed10aa2b5a0fcfe74f8a6f7611aeb346b06a1f99: Has:20e35c9169f2663d5adcb4c58f9da3f1279abd8d:
  Making dir :prebuilt_downloads:
  Downloading... https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-devel-2.0.18-VC.zip ed561079ec622b0bab5a9e02976f5d540b0622da
  Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\SDL2-devel-2.0.18-VC.zip:
  Downloading... https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/release/SDL2_image-devel-2.0.5-VC.zip 137f86474691f4e12e76e07d58d5920c8d844d5b
  Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\SDL2_image-devel-2.0.5-VC.zip:
  Downloading... https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/release/SDL2_ttf-devel-2.0.15-VC.zip 1436df41ebc47ac36e02ec9bda5699e80ff9bd27
  Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\SDL2_ttf-devel-2.0.15-VC.zip:
  Downloading... https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/release/SDL2_mixer-devel-2.0.4-VC.zip 9097148f4529cf19f805ccd007618dec280f0ecc
  Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\SDL2_mixer-devel-2.0.4-VC.zip:
  Downloading... https://www.pygame.org/ftp/jpegsr9d.zip ed10aa2b5a0fcfe74f8a6f7611aeb346b06a1f99
  
  ---
  For help with compilation see:
      https://www.pygame.org/wiki/CompileWindows
  To contribute to pygame development see:
      https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
  ---
  
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

Encountered error while generating package metadata.

See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Comment: Глянь тут, вроде давали ответ.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74188013/python-pygame-not-installing

Comment: @AliakseiLz, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Перевод [оригинального ответа со StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74188013/python-pygame-not-installing) для русскоязычного сообщества.
> Спасибо [@starbuck5](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13816541/starbuck5) за развёрнутый ответ!

**Короткий ответ**

Установите pygame с помощью `pip install pygame --pre` — это связано с версией установленного у вас Python.

**Длинный ответ**

Трейсбек показывает, что вы используете Python 3.11, который был выпущен недавно. Pygame это расширение на C, и поэтому оно нуждается в перевыпуске с новыми "wheels" (бинарники) для каждого нового минорного релиза Python (3.9, 3.10, 3.11, и т.д.)

Последний «полный» релиз pygame с версией 2.1.2 состоялся немного ранее и поставляется без wheels для 3.11, поэтому система пытается собрать pygame из исходников. Но, конечно, ей не удаётся этого сделать, потому как у вас не настроена среда разработки pygame.

Однако в последнем пре-релизе pygame под версией 2.1.3.dev8 (совсем недавний) есть wheels для 3.11, так что системе не придется компилировать pygame из исходников.

Как только pygame 2.1.3 будет в релизе, этот дополнительный флаг (который сообщает pip об установке предварительного релиза) больше не понадобится.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка происходит из-за версии Python. Ошибки показывают строки кода, в которых есть синтаксис питона версии> 3.10, который не поддерживается на питон ниже 3.9. Чтобы решить проблему,перейдите на версию питона 3.10 или же используйте команду:

## python3 -m pip install pygame --pre --user